# Char to ascii code conversion and back to char

Tags: c++, char, stdvector

I have small question:
I have:

```
std::vector<char> charArray(7);
std::vector<int> intArray(7);
int tempInt;
char tempChar;
```

Is it proper:

```
for(int i=0; i<charArray.size();i++)
{
    tempInt= static_cast<int>(charArray.at(i));
    intArray.at(i)=tempInt;
}
// some operations with elemets of intArray
// Like intArray.at(0) = intArray.at(1)^intArray.at(2);
// next back conversion to chars
for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
{
    tempChar=static_cast<char>(intArray.at(i));
    // Thanks to 
    charArray.at(i)=tempChar;
}
```

Is it right? Or should i use some other functions?

Comment: Is it "right" according to which requirements and constraints?

Comment: I have the feeling that you want to convert `'1'` to `1`, or `'A'` to `65`. Perhaps you should tell us what is the expected behaviour of your program.

Comment: @ChristianHackl nope. I want to make hamming parity bits to my chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static_cast<>` is perfectly fine for converting `char` to `int` and *vice versa*.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have a bug that will prevent compilation.

```
charArray=tempChar;
```

Should be:

```
charArray.at(i) = tempChar;
```

Once that's fixed, your snippet (assuming it forms part of a wider, well-formed program) is itself well-formed and does what I can only guess you wanted it to do.

Comment: This was type error. And user @Paul Evans answered my question.

Comment: @UNIm95: Next time post the actual code that you tested, in MCVE form, via copy/paste. Don't re-type it out. Because then you introduce mistakes.

Comment: Sorry but what is MCVE form? Our small project is written in such style.

Comment: @UNIm95: It can't be because your code does not even have a `main` function. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @UNIm95 MCVE stands for Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example. LRIO is saying you should have compiled and tested the code before posting it.

Comment: Thanks you two. I haven't forget this rule here. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard copy for this.

```
std::copy(intArray.begin(), intArray.end(), charArray.begin());
```

Unfortunately compilers may warn you are implicitly converting from a larger data type to a smaller one. We can fix that by using standard transform and a casting functor.

```
template<class Out_T, class In_T>
inline Out_T Convert(const In_T& x)
{
    return static_cast<Out_T>(x);
}

...

std::transform(intArray.begin(), intArray.end(), charArray.begin(), Convert<decltype(charArray)::value_type, decltype(intArray)::value_type>);
```

This is looking pretty ugly, so let's wrap it in a function.

```
template<class Input_Itr, class Output_Itr>
void ConvertRange(Input_Itr in, Input_Itr in_end, Output_Itr out)
{
    std::transform(in, in_end, out, Convert<typename std::iterator_traits<Output_Itr>::value_type, typename std::iterator_traits<Input_Itr>::value_type>);
}
```

Now you can simply call in your code:

```
ConvertRange(intArray.begin(), intArray.end(), charArray.end());
```

Comment: Nothing like a little overengineering on a Monday morning, eh?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It gets the juices flowing.